# Is this compile error typedef int (*j)() throw(A)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, typedef

```
#include <iostream>

class A {};

typedef int (*j)() throw(A);  

int f() 
{
    std::cout << "function f" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{ 
    j y = f;
    y();
}
```

In all sites and Stroustrup too says that there will be compile error, but it compiles.
Are there any changes in standard?

Comment: Which compiler and what version?

Comment: Microsoft visual studio 2012

Comment: Since you're claiming you will be throwing a `typename A` object in the prototype for `foo()` without actually having declared it yet, I can't see how it *isn't* a compiler error. You should get an undefined symbol for `A` or an "expected ')'" error.

Comment: Спецификация исключений не является частью типа функции, и в операторе 
typedef она не допускается. Например: 
typedefvoid (*PF) () throw(X) / //error

Comment: @ruakh No, you're right. Updated.

Comment: Straustrup just say thet typedef can't be right, i should write   class A
{
};

typedef int (*j)() throw(A);                                                 and it compiles

Comment: @GrigorApoyan What I'm saying is, as written above (with the class definition for `A` *after* the typedef that references it), I can't see how it *would* compile (and in fact, I just ran the above code verbatim through VS2012+NovCTP, and it does *not* compile). In other words, fix the code so it compiles as you claim it does in the question. *Edit the question; don't post a fix in a comment.*

Comment: this could be a compiler bug

Comment: MSVC is crap, I've already told you... Clang throws `baz.cpp:8:20: error: exception specifications are not allowed in typedefs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not an answer to this question -

MSVC 2010(that I have) throws no error, compiles fine and works without a hiccup

G++(GNU) says `error: 'j' declared with an exception specification`

Clang says `error: exception specifications are not allowed in typedefs`

Bottomline: Compiler bug in MSVC.

Comment: This is not a MSVC bug. It's a deliberate choice of MSVC to ignore most exception specifications: only `throw()` has an effect. Their parser still has to accept them, and apparently it accepts them too liberally. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfa0edys.aspx

Comment: @Sjoerd - deliberate or otherwise, it's a bug. The compiler does not correctly implement the C++ standard.

Comment: Any deviation from the standard is a bug @Sjoerd delibrate or otherwise!

Comment: and about the link @Sjoerd Microsoft has had a long history of projecting bugs as features! Nothing new from a company that "sells" its development tools.

Comment: Extensions are not deviations from the standard. If the standard doesn't require a diagnostic the compiler is perfectly compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Exception specifications are not part of the type of a function. You can't overload on them, for example; and a pointer-to-function does not carry an exception specification. As @Aniket says, it's a Microsoft bug that their compiler accepts that declaration.